# $scope vs instance variables and methods in controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am rewriting my AngularJS application using TypeScript.  In my application I have used $scope to define variables and methods:

```
defectResource.defectByDefectId($scope.defectid).then(function (data) {
   $scope.defect = data;
});

$scope.postDefect = function () {
   defectResource.postDefect($scope.defect).then(function () {
      $location.path('defects/' + $stateParams.itemid);
   });
};
```

I can rewrite my controller something like this:

```
interface IDefectDetailModel {
}

class DefectDetailController implements IDefectDetailModel {
    static $inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'defectResource', 'entityProvider'];

    constructor($scope: any, $stateParams: any, $location: any, defectResource: any, entityProvider: any) {
       defectResource.defectByDefectId($scope.defectid).then(function  (data) {
          $scope.defect = data;
       });

      $scope.postDefect = function () {
        defectResource.postDefect($scope.defect).then(function () {
           $location.path('defects/' + $stateParams.itemid);
        });
      };
    }
}
```

But if I understood correctly it is not good way. I need to create Interface and TypeScript class which will implement this interface. All my variables must be class variables (so `$scope.defectid` must be `this.defectid`) and all my `$scope` methods must be class methods (`this.postDefect()`).

Do I understood correctly? If I am using AngularJS with TypeScript the best way is not use `$scope` variables and methods and use only instance variables and methods (using `this`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am using AngularJS with TypeScript the best way is not use $scope variables and methods and use only instance variables and methods (using this) ?

+100.

Key reason being that scope variables are susceptible to become disconnected due to angular's scope inheritance mechanism. Even without TypeScript it is recommended *not to use scope varaibles* and this is why the `controller as` syntax was created.

More on Angular controllers in typescript: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E